# Does this combinator have a name?

Tags: python, function, combinators

This function f accepts an argument list and returns another callable with the same argument list, so that other functions can be applied to it.

```
from operator import add, mul

def f(*a, **kw):
    return lambda g: g(*a, **kw)

map(f(3, 10), (add, mul))  # -> [13, 30]
```

What do you call `f`? Is this a combinator of some kind?

Answer (score 4):

The combinator is a [curried](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying) form of [apply](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html?highlight=apply#apply). Compared to the (deprecated) built-in function `apply`, `f` reverses the order of the arguments to be more useful, providing what looks like a dual to the [functools.partial](http://docs.python.org/library/functools.html?highlight=partial#functools.partial) function.

Comment: With the (probably negligible) difference that a `partial` can be called with further arguments which get passed additionally.

Comment: I've significantly rewritten this, to correct for my having originally misread the question.

Answer (score 0):

It is quite closely related to `partial`, but not the same.

`partial` takes a function and some arguments and returns a callable which calls the given callable with the combined parameters.

```
def pr(x): print (x) # making it fit for 2.x and 3.x

p = functools.partial(pr, 1, 2, 3)
p() # prints 1, 2, 3

q = f(1, 2, 3)
p(pr) # prints 1, 2, 3
```